# JCheckBox dissapears when repaint is called

Tags: java, jcheckbox

I have a `JCheckBox` on top of an image, but whenever `repaint()` is called the `JCheckBox` disappears. If I click on the position where it initially was it becomes visible again.
I've tried setting it to `setVisible(true)` on every repaint but that didn't work.

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: You probably need to call repaint on the checkbox as well.

Comment: @svz Post it as an answer so he can accept it.

Comment: Something else is wrong. You should not need to call repaint on a component added to a panel. Swing should do this automatically. There is a design problem somewhere.